# I want to integrate my own app in Waze app

Tags: android, kotlin, waze

[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL8g9.jpg)

i have a service application that I created. I want to switch easily between two apps. Some apps are allowed. Is it possible to add my own application?i did not try anything because i don't know how can i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to check [the developers page provided by Waze](https://developers.google.com/waze). The example you show is the result of [the Waze Audio Kit](https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-audio), but what you are saying here seems to correspond more with [the Waze Transport SDK](https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-transport). Be aware though: these programs require an approval within Waze, so it's not as easy as just implementing an API.